# How to create conditional column in pandas dataframe using regex?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to create a conditional column `type` where:

- If the last part of the index starts with `01` to `09`, the label is `tumor` (for example, TCGA-06-0125-**02**A is `tumor`)
- Otherwise, label as `non-tumor` (e.g., TCGA-06-0125-**12**A is `non-tumor`)

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# 01-09 : tumor
# 10-19 : normal

# Color the PCA plot by tumor vs non-tumor 
condition = meth_450.loc[meth_450.index.contains('01') | meth_450.index.str.contains('02') | meth_450.index.str.contains('03') | meth_450.index.str.contains('04') | meth_450.index.str.contains('05') | meth_450.index.str.contains('06') | meth_450.index.str.contains('07')  | meth_450.index.str.contains('08') | meth_450.index.str.contains('09') ] 
label = "non-tumor"
meth_450["type"] = np.select(condition, label, default="tumor")
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-3f71a5ae2941> in <cell line: 8>()
      6 condition = meth_450.loc[meth_450.index.str.contains('11A')]
      7 label = "non-tumor"
----> 8 meth_450["type"] = np.select(condition, label, default="tumor")

/shared-libs/python3.10/py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py in select(*args, **kwargs)

/shared-libs/python3.10/py/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in select(condlist, choicelist, default)
    784     # Check the size of condlist and choicelist are the same, or abort.
    785     if len(condlist) != len(choicelist):
--> 786         raise ValueError(
    787             'list of cases must be same length as list of conditions')
    788 

ValueError: list of cases must be same length as list of conditions
```

Example `meth_450` dataframe (as dictionary):

```
meth_450 = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-06-0125-02A':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 'TCGA-06-0125-12A':[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 'TCGA-06-0125-04A':[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]})
```

Expected output:

|  | cg001 | cg002 | cg003 | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| TCGA-06-0125-02A | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 | tumor |
| TCGA-06-0125-12A | 0.4 | 0.5 | 0.6 | non-tumor |
| TCGA-06-0125-04A | 0.7 | 0.8 | 0.9 | tumor |

Answer (score 0):

You can use string methods with regex to find the rows that have an index where the last portion ends in 01-09:

```
meth_450 = pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-06-0125-02A':[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], 'TCGA-06-0125-12A':[0.4, 0.5, 0.6], 'TCGA-06-0125-04A':[0.7, 0.8, 0.9]})
meth_450 = meth_450.T.assign(type=(
    meth_450.T.index
    .str.split('-')
    .str[-1]
    .str.contains(r'^0[1-9]', regex=True)   
)).replace({'type':{True:'tumor', False:'non-tumor'}})
```

Output:

```
                    0    1    2       type
TCGA-06-0125-02A  0.1  0.2  0.3      tumor
TCGA-06-0125-12A  0.4  0.5  0.6  non-tumor
TCGA-06-0125-04A  0.7  0.8  0.9      tumor
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `np.where()` to assign tumor or non-tumor

```
import numpy as np

dft = meth_450.T
dft['type'] = np.where(dft.index.str.match('\w{4}-\d\d-\d{4}-0\d\w'),'tumor','non-tumor')
```

**Result**

```
                    0    1    2       type
TCGA-06-0125-02A  0.1  0.2  0.3      tumor
TCGA-06-0125-12A  0.4  0.5  0.6  non-tumor
TCGA-06-0125-04A  0.7  0.8  0.9      tumor
```